# Real time feedback on swipe XCode

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've managed to change views with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but it only starts changing the view after I do the complete swipe. How can I make it start as soon as I start dragging my finger on the screen? I've searched but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Pan gesture

```
     UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
     [self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Then do:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:YOUR_VIEW];
    UIView *draggedView = [gesture view];

    switch ([gesture state]) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:    
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            break;

        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GestureRecognizers will wait until it is certain which gesture was made. This is why they always have a bit of delay. One way of doing this otherwise is to implement your own swipe handler. E.g. You can use touchesBegan: touchesEnded: touchesMoved: and TouchesCancelled: -methods.

(Remember to enable these methods by enabling userInteractionEnabled property for your node(s))

```
// SKScene init
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
     // register that touch(es) began
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Calculate which way touch(es) is/are moving
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Register that touch(es) ended
}
```

Comment: Pan gesture recognizers keep giving you callbacks as your move your finger.

Comment: And I never said it would not. I was just noting that (certain) gesture recognizers (like swipe) always have a bit of delay before triggering. That is why they may not suit well for cases where instant feedback is required. 

And, indeed, you could use PanGestureRecognizer for implementing your own swipe gesture. I just suggested another approach for registering the touches.